# Angular get current route param within a promise?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

I need to get the current route id within my ngOnInit in a promise and after I got the id value, I want to continue working with the id.

I've tried something like this :

```
var temp = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

// and doing something with it here
```

and

```
this.route.params.toPromise().then(data => {
// doing something with it here
});
```

Sadly it's always null, even if my url is like 'localhost:4200/answer/1248523'
It need to happen inside the ngOnInit.
How do I get the current id asynchronous?

I've created a navigation bar to switch between different components in my app.component.html and basically I want to keep the paramId when switching between components/doing routing.

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar mat-align-tabs="center">
    <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" [routerLink]="link.link" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
        [active]="rla.isActive">
        {{link.label}}
    </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

my component.ts

```
constructor(private router: Router,private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.navLinks = [
      {
        label:'info',
        link:'./information',
        index:0
      }, {
        label: 'theme',
        link:'./theme',
        index:1
      },
      {
        label: 'form',
        link: './form',
        index: 2
      }, {
        label: 'attach',
        link: './attach',
        index: 3
      }, {
        label: 'testSum',
        link: './testSum',
        index: 4
      },
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var paramId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.router.events.subscribe((res) => {

      if(this.router.url.indexOf("answer") !== -1) {
        this.navLinks = [
          {
            label: 'Summary',
            link: './answer/:id',
            index: 0
          }, {
            label: 'Inbox',
            link: ['./inbox',paramId],
            index: 1
          }
        ];
      }  
      this.activeLinkIndex = this.navLinks.indexOf(this.navLinks.find(tab => tab.link === '.' + this.router.url));
    });
  }
```

Also my routing looks for inbox and answer is this :

```
{ path: 'answer/:id', component: AnswerSummaryComponent},
{ path: 'inbox/:id', component: InboxComponent}
```

So basically the Navigation bar got a standard array for navigation (info,theme,form,attach,testSum) but If someone visits the site/app with a link like (localhost:4200/answer....) it should display different navigations. This works perfectly fine.
If someone visits the site with lets say : localhost:4200/answer/123123 he see's the Summary component and if he navigates to the Inbox I want the url to stay "localhost:4200/inbox/123123" but the url changes to "localhost:4200/inbox". So I wanted to pass the current current idParam in the link(object property) itself.

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] - how is the route configured? Also note [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route) recommend `paramMap`, not `params`, and Angular's based around observables, rather than promises, for async actions.

Comment: Why do you exactly need it to be a ```Promise```?

Comment: I strongly advise that you learn about [Observables and reactive programming here](http://learnrxjs.io).

Comment: Added a better example.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this :

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

...

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {  
      // Do Something with the params you receive
      let id = params.get('id');
    }
}
```

this.route.params returns an Observable to which u can subscribe.

Kind regards

Comment: Sorry I confused ParamMap and params. I updated my answer. kind regards